# How to use a mail as a solid proof

Tags: email

I have an e-mail that certifies a grade I received and I need to inform a boss. I only have this e-mail as proof that I actually received this grade so I need to use it. I thought about forwarding it to the concerned person but it is possible for anyone to change the content of the mail before. It is the same for a screenshot taken from the mailbox.

What is the best way to use an e-mail as proof so the person who gets it is confident enough about its authenticity?

Comment: Either get a certificate, or (after talking to the person who issued the grade) include them in the CC section.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace alexisg! I'm putting this on hold temporarily so you can clarify what exactly you're looking for here. As Joe mentioned there are a number of ways in which "proof" can be interpreted Can you share details on the context and what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: If someone can change it in route, then it's conceivable to someone else that you changed it before sending it. If it's what you consider "proof" then the burden of authenticity you're placing on it doesn't even exist with you.

Comment: Using Outlook 2010 and up you can always add received email message as attachments to another email. That way it is read only msg type file

Answer (score 3):

Email, unless digitally signed is quite easy to tamper with. But so is Paper - it is just more common.

In both cases the certifying body should be able to confirm the validity of your successful certificate to your boss, if he is in doubt.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine, the reliability of e-mail evidence will be subject to scrutiny. You can also talk to the issuer (the grade) to get a certificate as a valid and realiable proof in the future, if not e-mail should be sufficient, the rest regarding the validity is all up to you (skills related to that grade).

Answer (score 0):

The only method is to request the sending body to [digitally sign the email](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2007-resource-kit/cc545901(v=office.12)), this then adds a verification to the email that shows if it has been tampered.

But this is extreme and unlikely such a company would do it. Instead, I would send the email on to the boss as is with an added note that you will hand in the formal certificate (Or similar item received) when you have received it for further verification.

If the boss asks any further questions, then you can handle that issue as it comes.